# Python String Concatenation in for loop long strings

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, string-concatenation

I've heard couple of times already that you shouldn't do string concatenation in a for loop as strings are immutable and so it would compute the concatenation as a new string instance and then reassign the identifier. So if the result has n characters the time complexity would be O(n^2)

## **Bad:** runs in O(n^2). Iterative '+' concatenation.

```
letters = ""
for c in document:
    if c.isalpha():
        letters += c
```

## **Good:** runs in O(n). Iterative append, with a final "".join()

```
document = ""
temp = []
for c in document:
    if c.isalpha(): 
        temp.append(c)
letters = "".join(temp)
```

At the same time I've read that

**"Some later implementations of the Python interpreter have developed an optimization to allow such code to complete in linear time,.."**

So the first solution should be fine too? Is it an optimization which is in the latest python builds?

Comment: Most pythonistas would use the comprehension: `letters = ''.join([c for c in document if c.isalpha()])`

Comment: @StefanPochmann sorry my bad, letters should be outside of the loop. copy paste error. Corrected both snippets.

Comment: @user1767754 First one still has syntax error in first line. And a strange comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should write the most readable code for you; only if you have issues with the runtime, you should think of optimization:

```
letters = "".join(c for c in document if c.isalpha())
```

For current CPython implementations `join` is faster than '+'.

```
>>> def test():
...   s = ""
...   for x in range(1000):
...     s += 'x'
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(test)
157.9563412159987
>>> def test():
...   s = []
...   for x in range(1000):
...     s.append('x')
...   s = ''.join(s)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(test)
147.74276081599965
```

Comment: list comp is better than genex here

Comment: it's pretty the same.

Comment: My question might be not clear, but i wanted to know if python is optimized for doing += or not.

Comment: That depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The key is *some* implementations. Not all. If you want to make sure your code runs fast on all implementations of python then use `str.join`. Depending on the size of your document, different approaches will be faster. However, `"".join(...)` is very pythonic and people will more quickly understand your intentions. So unless you have *lots* of *small* documents stick with `str.join`.

However, to get a 10-fold speed increase on both `str.join` and `+=` then use `str.translate`. This solution is specific to removing individual characters though.

```
from string import digits
translation_table = str.maketrans("", "", digits) 
# first two args about translating characters, third is for removing characters
letters = document.translate(translation_table)
```

The reason for this speed increase is that python needs to create a new string for each character in the document. `str.translate` doesn't need to do this and so is much faster.